# Excel files are not supported in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

Till now i am using SSIS in Xp Operating System but now i had move to Windows 7.I have

Microsoft Office 2007 installed in my machine.When i am trying to use Excel Source in Windows7

,its is showing Error that 64 bit cannot support Excel Files.

Please tell me what is the exact problem may be & how to get rid of that...?

Comment: Hi Akash88 ,You want to say that Excel does not support in Window 7....I don't think the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your package in 32-bit mode. Here is a [usefull link](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/cannot-execute-ssis/).

Comment: Hey, That was the exact thing i was looking for...Thanks

Comment: But i am not able to open the First image as it was present in your link.Can you please help me out on that....still strugling

Comment: It is on MS SQL Server Management Server. As I understand you need the second image.

Comment: Hi demas,i am unable to open the second image also in my machine.Can you please provide me step by step execution of that.I am not getting even the first option to start.../ Thanks in advance

Comment: Project Properties -> Debugging -> Run64BitRuntime (it is in main menu of Visual Studio)